# Show that $2^{2^n} = (\prod {p_i^{a_i}}\equiv 2^{n+1}\alpha_ix_i+1) \mod 2^{2n+2}\implies 2^{n+1} (x_1 \alpha_1 + \dots + x_k\alpha_k ) $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

I had doubt in the following solution. However I couldn't understand the part " For this, it is enough to show that $x_i (\alpha_1 +\dots + \alpha_k ) \ge 2^{n+1}$"

[image]

Then the author proceeded with  showing that $2^{2^n} = (\prod {p_i^{a_i}}\equiv 2^{n+1}\alpha_ix_i+1) \mod 2^{2n+2}\implies 2^{n+1} (x_1 \alpha_1 + \dots + x_k\alpha_k ) \equiv  0 (\mod 2^{2n+2} )$ which I couldn't understand. Rest everything I did.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to me to just be writing out the equation (IE verifying the steps that were skipped, maybe with a slight typo). Can you elaborate on what you do not understand?

Answer (score 0):

Just write it out one step at a time. Which of the following statements do you not understand? (These build up from the previous statements, and from what was stated in the solution before "Now if we can show that $x_i \geq 2(n+1)$".)

1. $ 2^ { 2^n} +1 = \prod p_i ^ {\alpha_i } $
2. $ p_i ^{\alpha_i } = (2^{n+1} x_i + 1 ) ^{\alpha_i} \equiv 2^{n+1} \alpha_i x_i + 1 \pmod{2^{2n+2}}$.
3. $ \prod p_i ^ { \alpha_i } \equiv \prod (2^{n+1} \alpha_i x_i + 1 ) \pmod{2^{2n+2}} $
4. $\prod (2^{n+1} \alpha_i x_i + 1 ) \equiv 2^{n+1} (\sum \alpha_i x_i) + 1 \pmod{2^{2n+2}} $
5. $0 \equiv 2^{n+1} ( \sum \alpha_i x_i ) \pmod{2^{2n+2}} $.
6. Hence, $\sum \alpha_i x_i \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{n+1} }$.
7. $ \sum \alpha_i x_i \geq 2^{n+1}$.
8. $\exists I$ such that $ x_I \sum \alpha_i \geq 2^{n+1}$.
9. Since  $\sum \alpha_i \leq \frac{2^n}{n+1}$, hence $x_I \geq 2(n+1)$.

---

What is the "stronger bound" which the solution purports?